# How do I draw a quadrilateral with rounded corners in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to create the following shape using Kivy's canvas instructions:

[image: A quadrilateral with rounded corners]

I have successfully managed to create a trapezium with straight corners (code below),

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: root.background_color
    Quad:
        points: [self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y + self.height, self.x + (1.5*self.width), self.y + self.height, self.x + self.width, self.y]
```

but was wondering if the same is possible with rounded corners?

I can think of a work around, which would be to save a white image of the rounded trapezium, then texture a rectangle with this image. Something like...

```
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: self.background_color
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        source: 'rounded_trapezium.png'
```

Now `background_color` would 'tint' the white trapezium to whatever colour I wanted, meaning I could add and recolour the same shape several times without having to save and load lots of images. But I am curious whether the same can be achieved just using Kivy's canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a Mesh instruction you can create any shape you like, but you'll need to write code to generate its vertices. You may find it useful to look at the code for the RoundedRectangle canvas instruction since what you want is the same but with one of the corners of the bounding rectangle offset.

Comment: Thanks @inclement I'll look into Mesh instructions. I am having some trouble finding the Cavas/Graphic Instruction source code. Any chance you can send me a link?

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx#L1265

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an example like this, to get the quadrilateral you want, you will need to edit the `radius` argument

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = ("""
BoxLayout:
    padding: 50
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.43, 0.85, 0.56, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [(200, 100), (200, 40), (self.size[0], self.size[0]), (20, 20)]
""")


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```